# How to call more functions on completing user signup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-authentication

I am creating a login function with react and firebase, i want to call two more functions on  completing signup, I tried doing

```
  const signUpSubmit = (e,closeSignUpCard,openSignInCard) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const email = e.target.email.value;
      const password = e.target.password.value;

      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then(() => {
        closeSignUpCard();
        openSignInCard();
    }
    .catch((error) => {
          alert(error.message);
    });
};
```

but it shows error:

```
closeSignUpCard is not defined
openSignInCard is not defined
```

is there any other way to go about doing this? btw, i'm using firebase:^9.1.0

Comment: How are you passing those functions into the `signInSubmit` function?

Comment: <button type="submit" onClick={()=>signUpSubmit(closeSignUpCard,openSignInCard)}>Sign Up</button>

Comment: And where are those coming from? Somewhere along the line, those functions are not being passed correctly, because they are showing up as undefined.

Comment: It seems the two argument functions are not present in the code yet, when passed to the onclick event. are they methods of the react component? Have you tried signUpSubmit( this.closeSignUpCard, this.openSignInCard)?

Comment: Please take the [tour]. We don't mark questions as [fixed] or put answers in questions.

Answer (score -1):

You could turn your signUpSubmit function into an async funcion, and just await for the internal promises to end. This way you don't need to get into a callback hell and still things will happen after events you have some kind of control.

Also, if the `openSignInCard` function **must** be executed after the `closeSignUpCard` function, you can turn them into async functions and use await before they are called, so the next one will only be called after the first one ends.

Remember to be careful of using too much awaits. You know, users don't like waiting too much

```js
const signUpSubmit = async (e, closeSignUpCard, openSignInCard) {
   e.preventDefault()
   const email = e.target.email.value
   const password = e.target.password.value

   const signIn = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then(r => { return { success: true } })
      .catch(e => { return { success: false, error: e.message })

   if ( signIn.success ){
      closeSignUpCard()
      openSignInCard()
   } else {
      alert(signIn.error)
   }
}
```